# loop with struct fields and plot (changing plot styles) - matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop, struct, plot, eval

that's a thing that is making me a bit crazy-noob so far.

I have my struct storing data from successive experiments, 7 field per each experiment:

- veq1
- rpmdispl1
- displ1
- tau1
- sigma1
- mu1
- v_displ1
- veq2
- ...

Then i'd like to plot in for loops, like (k is total datasets to be plotted)

```
    figure(1)
    hold all
    for ii=1:k;
        subplot(2,1,1)
        eval(['plot(struct.displ',num2str(ii),',struct.tau',num2str(ii),')']); 
        subplot(2,1,2)
        eval(['plot(struct.displ',num2str(ii),',struct.v_displ',num2str(ii),')']);
    end
```

But actually I am not allowed in changing plot axes style among the plots of the loop. (using either roots or gca settings, line and color string variables, etc)

So i thought to do it in a different way, like:

```
    for ii=1:k;
        subplot(2,1,1)
        plot(struct.displ(num2str(ii)),struct.tau(num2str(ii)),line,color)
        subplot(2,1,2)
        plot(struct.displ(num2str(ii)),struct.v_displ(num2str(ii)),line,color); 
    end
```

But no way. This last is only an idea (rather than a working code), I admit it. Can somebody suggest me something to work it out?

I'd be grateful.

Comment: The way your struct is formed is not good MATLAB practice in the first place. If you can restructure it to be struct(n).veq and so on (for n = 1:7 and for each of your fields), your life will be much easier.

Comment: If you find yourself sticking numbers on the end of variable names, that's a clear sign you should be using a higher-dimension array.

Comment: Thanks for comments, I'll proceed restructuring the struct.